# Issue with sequelize, can't use findAll

Tags: javascript, express, sequelize.js

I'm starting out with Sequelize and got kind of stuck right there. I try to connect my controller, route, model and stuff and I get this error when trying to access my route (localhost:3000/api/carousel) :

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'findAll')
    at getAllCarouselItems (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\controllers\carousel-item_controller.js:6:47)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)      
    at next (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:144:13)
    at Route.dispatch (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\route.js:114:3)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)      
    at C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:15
    at Function.process_params (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:346:12)
    at next (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:280:10)
    at Function.handle (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:175:3)
    at router (C:\Users\theob\OneDrive\Documents\DEV\le_burguignon\back\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:47:12)
```

And here's my controller where the findAll method just won't work:

```
const CarouselItem = require('../models/carousel-item');
const db = require('../config/sequelize');

async function getAllCarouselItems(req, res) {
    try {
        const carouselItems = await db.CarouselItem.findAll();
        res.json(carouselItems);
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        res.status(500).json({ message: 'Server Error' });
    }
}

module.exports = { getAllCarouselItems };
```

Is there something I've been missing?

I tried using console logs, searching online using these errors, even asking chat gpt for help but being a beginner with this technology, I get confused and am not sure where to look at.

Comment: The error indicates that there's no `db.CarouselItem`. Maybe you meant `CarouselItem.findAll()`, since you did `const CarouselItem = ...`.

Comment: If `carousel-item` is your model then as @Barmar says the `findAll` method should be called on the model not on whatever you think `db.CarouselItem` is. If you post the code for `models/carousel-item` then someone will be able to help you debug.

Answer (score 0):

So basically I added :

```
sequelize
    .authenticate()
    .then(() => {
        console.log('Connection has been established successfully.');
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.error('Unable to connect to the database: ', error);
    });
```

in my app.js, and it worked, even tho I am not sure if I was mistaken about authenticate() being something you use to test the connexion.

As for db, I removed it.